# What is the best way to pass data from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, data-transfer

I am trying to build a system where my python instance has threads of processes and my PHP code requesting data from that running python instance. The only way that I found is openning a socket in python instance and requesting some data from PHP. And it needs to interchange data like requesting some data from python and then sending response data from PHP to Python. I wanted to ask if there is any other options available because opening sockets and sending data over them is not very convenient where you have everything in your server but accessing in a roundabout way.

**EDIT:**
To make it clear i will tell how the system will actually work. I will have a website which will have some sort of json data in it and it will send that data to my running Python instance so that this Python instance can run functions (I can not run those functions in PHP because there is no library for PHP of my code.) to process that json data and will return that processed json data back to the PHP.

Comment: This is sort of an opinion-y question, maybe specify requirements more and explain why what you'redoing doesn't work? As is I would recommend using JSON, XML, or Thrift as a data format and while reading off a socket works a message queue or even an HTTP server could be easier/more flexible. That's may be substantial overhead though, depending on your context.

Comment: I mean it works just as is but i just wanted to ask if there are any other solutions. The data will be just json objects turning around python and php. Input will come from php in json to python and in python (which has an already running thread or in other words session) the program will execute some commands in a running thread and will return a processed json object. It will execute commands which i can not use in PHP so I need to use Python.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the processing you need to do on the JSON data? I highly doubt there aren't native PHP functions that can't do anything that Python can do.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is run the python program by exec and pass data as command line argument .

```
<?php
    $result = exec("python filename.py data");
?>
```

or you can write the data to a file and pass the filename as argument and read the data file in python.

**Note**
Use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() when passing to exec function to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands.